# Create txt file template with django email

Tags: python, django, text, django-email

I have a question according to emails generated in my `Django` application. I created an `HTML file`, but I have question with my `txt file` and tags used.

In my HTML file:

- links look like: `<a href="....">My link</a>`
- bold looks like: `<b>My text</b>`
- variables look like: `{{ my_variable }}`

But in my txt file, HTML tags work ? How I can display links and bold text in my .txt file which will send by email ?

Thank you very much,

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. How would a link work in a text file?

Comment: No, `.txt` files are plain text files, you cannot just use formatting like that. To use formatting you have to use HTML files.

Comment: Why don't you send the email in html?